# Will Incremental ID solve the Radio Button behavior issue with clone()?

Tags: jquery, radio-button, nested, clone, increment

I have several issues, none of which I have successfully resolved individually. I read through all the Q&A regarding cloned radio buttons and then tried many if not most of the incremental ID solutions before posting here.

Successful code eludes me. There is a JSFiddle link at the bottom!

1) I would like to use an increment to change the name&id on the cloned elements

I [think] would prefer to use this method which failed mostly because I didn't know what to put where (i.e. "??") - another method is certainly welcome:

```
var regex = /^(.*)(\d)+$/i;
var cloneIndex = $(".newloc").length;

$("button.clone").live("click", function(){
$(this).parents(".newloc").clone()
    .appendTo("#location_container")
    .attr("id", "newloc" +  cloneIndex)
    .find("??").each(function() {
        var id = this.id || "";
        var match = id.match(regex) || [];
        if (match.length == 3) {
            this.id = match[1] + (cloneIndex);
        }
});
cloneIndex++;
```

});

2) My research suggests that the previous will resolve the cloned radio-button misbehavior

3) Nested in the cloned div is a JQuery, dependent on radio-button selection, operates in the source, but fails in the clones.

4) Try as I might, I cannot figure out a remove last clone script for a remove-button function - so easy, I'm sure I'm missing something painfully obvious.  This fails:

```
$("button.remove").live("click", function(){
$(this).parents(".newloc").remove();
```

});

5) I would love it if the screen scrolled down to show the top of the new clone at the top of the frame.

All this sounds rather easy in theory, but after 5 days and a weekend, I feel stuck and frustrated and so I appeal to you for aid and assistance.

[I made a JSFiddle of my current solution here.](http://jsfiddle.net/RenHue/RhDbK/18/)

You assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does.  All my issues were answered!

With the help of a talented UC Berkeley student - thanks jerry!

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

    $('.remove').hide();//hiding the remove button
     var radioCounter = 0;
    // var prot = $(document).find('.newloc');

    $('.add').click(function () {

        //Preserve original location settings (first two in the list all times)
        //The reason for this if because when the form is first cloned, the names
        //of the radio buttons have not been changed yet, so the value of the original
        //radio buttons are lost, so we need to preserve them and then re-set them to
        //accordingly later.
        var originalConfVal = $('input[name="conference[0]"]:checked').val();
        var originalRoleVal = $('input[name="role[0]"]:checked').val();

        // this duplicates the section, and clears the values in the clone, adds a new class and places the clone
        $('.add_location').clone(true).find('input:not(:radio)').val("").end().removeClass("add_location").addClass("newloc").appendTo($('#location_container'));
        $('.newloc').find('.remove').show();
        //Set correct incremented names
        radioCounter += 1;

        var $allConfs = $('.authradio[name^="conference["]');
        var $allRoles = $('.authradio[name^="role["]');

        //Get last two conference authradios and set incremented names
        $allConfs.slice(-2, $allConfs.length).attr('name', 'conference[' + radioCounter + ']');

        //Get last 3 role authradios and set incremented names
        $allRoles.slice(-3, $allRoles.length).attr('name', 'role[' + radioCounter + ']');

        //Make the newly cloned radio buttons be checked at "no" for conference
        $('input[name="conference[' + radioCounter + ']"][value="no"]').prop("checked", "checked");
        $('input[name="role[' + radioCounter + ']"][value="Attendee"]').prop("checked", "checked");

        //Hide new sliding conference menu
        $('.hideme:last').hide();

        //Reset original radio buttons to preserved values
        $('input[name="conference[0]"][value="' + originalConfVal + '"]').prop("checked", "checked");
        $('input[name="role[0]"][value="' + originalRoleVal + '"]').prop("checked", "checked");

// -- ---------------------------------------------------- -->
        // this fixes the date picker repetition issue
        $('.authdepart:last').removeClass('hasDatepicker').attr('id', "").datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            showButtonPanel: true
        });
        $('.authreturn:last').removeClass('hasDatepicker').attr('id', "").datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            showButtonPanel: true
        });

        // clone styling
         $('.newloc:last').prepend(
        $('<div/>').addClass("auth_98").css('border', 'none').append(
        $('<legend/>').append('New Location')));    

         //Scroll container
        $('#location_container').animate({scrollTop: $('#location_container')[0].scrollHeight}, "slow");

    });

    $('.hideme').hide();

    $('.authradio').on('change', function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 'yes') $(this).parent().find('.hideme').slideDown();
        else $(this).parent().find('.hideme').slideUp();
    });

    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        showButtonPanel: true
    });

    $("button.remove").on("click", function(){
        $(this).parents(".newloc").remove();
   });

});
```